# como incluir el resultado de una consulta sql en un componente <Select/> de react

Tags: mysql, reactjs

Estoy tratando de mostrar en un componente Select de react una lista catalogo obtenida por una consulta en MySQL, pero en el formulario solo me muestra el componente del select y no me muestra los datos obtenidos de la consulta:
[image: Componente Select en donde deseo incluir el resultado de la consulta sql]

estoy un poco desesperado, porque no logro que aparezcan los datos, a continuacion muestro el ultimo metodo que he implementado, que es por medio de una api:
[image: Parte 1 del archivo en donde se encuentra el componente del]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En estos ultimos muestro los archivos que controlan el componente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo anexo el archivo de la API, para proceder con la ejecucion de la consulta y la obtencion de la data que pretendo mostrar en el Select:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas Carlos y bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Por favor, intenta no añadir tu código en imágenes. Revisa [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Revisa la línea `options = (data.map(...))`. Estás pasando ```{label: `{sup.Loc}`}```. No se si debería ser ```{label: `${sup.Loc}`}``` o `{label: sup.Loc}` directamente. Lo mismo con el value. Notar también que en la API php no se ve que estés usando el id de la consulta.

Comment: Gracias por la recomendacion de las imagenes del codigo, lo tomare en cuenta, en este momento estoy en otro lugar, te incluire el codigo textual el dia de mañana para que lo puedas analizar

Comment: la linea options = {data.map(sup=>({label: sup.Loc, value: sup.Loc}))}; tambien la he probada de esta forma sin las backtips, y queda igual, no me muestra nada en el componente.

Comment: Una pregunta, habra una forma mas practica de ejecutar el sql, talvez en alguno de los archivos, y no utilizar la API, ya que considero que es una consulta sencilla.  Quedo a la espera de sus comentarios y gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Ejecutar la consulta SQL en el cliente sería un grave error. Podrías hacerlo en tu código React si tuvieses SSR.